# adaptive linear combiner with the use of steepest descent algorithm

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code for adaptive linear combiner (steepest descent) with random signal added at the input.:M=16;

```
M=16;
k=[1:200];
R=[0.5 0.46;0.46 0.5];
P=[0;-0.38];
wstar=[-5 30];
s=sin((2*pi*k)/M);  %input signal
d=cos((2*pi*k)/M);  %desired signal
**x=s+randn(1,M);** %input signal + noise
mu=1;
for i=1:M           %steepest descent algorithm
    w(1)=wstar;
    g(i)=2*R*w(i)-2*P;
    w(i+1)=w(i)+mu*(-g(i));
end
for i=1:M
    y(i) = sum(w(i)*x(i),w(i+1)*x(i+1)); %output signal
    e(i) = d(i)-y(i);  %error signal
end
subplot(221),plot(k,d),ylabel('Desired Signal');
subplot(222),plot(k,s),ylabel('Input Signal+Noise');
subplot(223),plot(k,e),ylabel('Error');
subplot(224),plot(k,y),ylabel('Adaptive Desired output');
```

For some reason it says there's an error at x=s+randn(1,N). Can someone let me know where I have gone wrong??

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: s is a 1x200 matrix, while randn(1,M) is 1x16. You can't add them up

Comment: randn(1,M) what are you expecting this do output? It produced 16 normally distrubted random variables with mean 0 and stddev of 1. If you don't want standard normal noise try: x = s + (mean + stddev.*randn(200,1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a vector of length 200 (because `k = 1:200`), and you're adding to it `randn(1, M)`, which is a vector of length `M = 16`. How are those supposed to add together?